# SQL - Create pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a pivot table from data in a number of tables, but I can't get it to work. 
This is the database structure:

[image]

So the tables would look like:

[image]

What I would like to create is a pivot table combining all sales data from customers per product like this:

[image]

(This data is to be fed into a different system which requires this as input, so I can't change the format)

However, I have no idea how to accomplish this. 
I tried this:

```
select distinct c.name, 
       p.name,
       sum(p.price)        
FROM customer c
  left join sale s on c.customerId = s.customerId
  left outer join product p ON s.productId = p.productId
group by s.productId, s.customerId
```

I know it's not much, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.
Can anyone help me get on track?

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: How many products you may have ?

Comment: SQL can't pivot an arbitrary number of columns without excessive trickery. Is it an option to pivot in your client application?

Comment: 2 questions and I might be able to help you: 1. Is there a new table where this result will be stored? 2. Do you know what a stored procedure is and can you use them?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: The only way I see this working is looping through the user table and the product table and inserting rows with the counts for each product for each user into a new table while using a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, you can pivot it by custom case when statements:

```
select c.name, 
sum(CASE WHEN p.name = 'Product X' THEN p.price ELSE 0 END) AS "Product X",
sum(CASE WHEN p.name = 'Product Y' THEN p.price ELSE 0 END) AS "Product Y",
sum(CASE WHEN p.name = 'Product Z' THEN p.price ELSE 0 END) AS "Product Z"
    FROM customer c
      left join sale s on c.customerId = s.customerId
      left outer join product p ON s.productId = p.productId
    group by c.customerId, c.name
```